# Why "event code 3005" with Event message "An unhandled exception has occurred" is triggered?

Tags: c#, asp.net

It looks that once a day this error is logged.

This is the logging I have from client:

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 11-2-2019 09:38:55 
Event time (UTC): 11-2-2019 08:38:55 
Event ID: e1bc004346904125a244dbbc5f960710 
Event sequence: 2024 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131943410407985469 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot...\ 
    Machine name: PRO01

Process information: 
    Process ID: 540 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL...

Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Davanti.WMS.RF.Common.SiteMaster.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Request information: 
    Request URL: https://...:8080/Pages/Authentication/Login.aspx 
    Request path: /Pages/Authentication/Login.aspx 
    User host address: 
    User:
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL...

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 18 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at ...WMS.RF.Common.SiteMaster.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

So looking into SiteMaster.cs I see this. The fact is that I don't see any issue with this. Can you help me on spotting it?

```
 public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    private readonly string WT4100 = "WT4100";
    private readonly string MC9200 = "MC9200";

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        if (!Page.Request.Path.EndsWith("/Login.aspx") && Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Authentication/Login.aspx");
        }

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "InitializeEventHandlers", "focusController.initializeFocusController(false);", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "InitializeCustomScrollbar", "toggleScrollBarVisibility();", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "InitializeWindowResize", "handleResizeEvent();", true);

        // a special stylesheet needs to be used for landscape device
        if (Request != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.UserAgent))
        {
            if (Request.UserAgent.Contains(WT4100))
            {
                IsWT41NO.Value = true.ToString();
            }
            else if (Request.UserAgent.Contains(MC9200))
            {
                IsMC92NO.Value = true.ToString();
            }
        }

        LiteralControl mainCssStyleSheet = new LiteralControl();            

        if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].ToLower().Contains("android"))
        {
            mainCssStyleSheet.Text = "<link href=\"../../Styles/Common/Android/Site.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">";
        }
        else
        {
            mainCssStyleSheet.Text = "<link href=\"../../Styles/Common/Site.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">";
        }

        MainCssPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(mainCssStyleSheet);

        LiteralControl specialDeviceCssStyleSheet = new LiteralControl();

        if (IsWT41NODevice)
        {
            specialDeviceCssStyleSheet.Text = "<link href=\"../../Styles/Common/WT41NO/Site.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">";
        }
        else if (IsMC92NODevice)
        {
            specialDeviceCssStyleSheet.Text = "<link href=\"../../Styles/Common/Site_MC92NO.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">";
        }

        MainCssPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(specialDeviceCssStyleSheet);

        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            string javaScriptCoraxRFSystemSetting = WMSSystemSetting.Get_JavaScriptCoraxRF(session);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(javaScriptCoraxRFSystemSetting))
            {
                LiteralControl javaScriptCoraxRF = new LiteralControl();
                javaScriptCoraxRF.Text = string.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\"></script>", javaScriptCoraxRFSystemSetting);
                BottomPageContent.Controls.Add(javaScriptCoraxRF);
            }

            RfLayoutOption rfLayoutOption = RfLayoutOption.Default;

            if (!PageHelper.IsSessionVariableSet(SessionConstants.SiteStyle))
            {
                rfLayoutOption = WMSSystemSetting.Get_RfLayout(session);
                Session[SessionConstants.SiteStyle] = rfLayoutOption;
            }
            else
            {
                rfLayoutOption = (RfLayoutOption)Enum.Parse(typeof(RfLayoutOption), Session[SessionConstants.SiteStyle].ToString());
            }

            AddStyleAccordingToRfLayout(rfLayoutOption);
        }


        if (!this.DesignMode && !IsPostBack)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FocusFirstInput", "focusController.focusFirstControl();", true);

            // disable client-side caching, so that the user is redirected to the loginpage 
            // when clicking browser back button after logout                
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
            Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

            if (!Page.Request.Path.EndsWith("/Login.aspx") && !SecuritySystem.Instance.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Authentication/Login.aspx");
            }
            if (Page.Request.Path.EndsWith("/Login.aspx"))
            {
                AIC.Text = "version " + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
            }
        }
    } ...
```

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong to me...why not wrap the whole thing in a `try{} catch{}` and log it, that way you should get the line number in the stack trace

Comment: I found out that issue is when I do a redirect, at these lines
 if (!Page.Request.Path.EndsWith("/Login.aspx") && !SecuritySystem.Instance.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Authentication/Login.aspx");
            }
I am checking to see what I can do about it...